# Stack overflow: infinite recursion X\==Y?

Tags: prolog

This is my program:

```
depends(apple, tree).
depends(cider, apple).

depends(X,Y) :- X\==Y, depends(Z,Y),depends(X,Y).
```

If I ask the following question:

```
depends(cider, tree).
```

I get:

```
GNU Prolog 1.3.0
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2007 Daniel Diaz
| ?- [apples].
apples.pro for byte code...
apples.pro compiled, 4 lines read - 765 bytes written, 28 ms

yes
| ?- depends(cider, tree).

Fatal Error: local stack overflow (size: 8192 Kb, environment variable used: LOCALSZ)
```

If I run a 'trace.', I can see the evaluation of X\==Y being repeated over and over....

What have I done wrong here ? (aside from buying a copy of '[Seven Languages in Seven Weeks](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Seven-Languages-Weeks-Programming-ebook/dp/B00AYQNR46/ref=sr_1_1?s=digital-text&ie=UTF8&qid=1368816707&sr=1-1&keywords=seven%20languages%20in%20seven%20weeks)' :-) )

EDIT:

So this works thanks to the notes from Daniel Lyons below : differentiating the names of facts from the names of rules prevented the recursion:

```
depends(apple, tree).
depends(cider, apple).

depends_on(X,Y) :- depends(X,Z),depends(Z,Y).
```

Gives the following (with 'trace' switched on):

```
{trace}
| ?- depends_on(cider, tree).
      1    1  Call: depends_on(cider,tree) ? 
      2    2  Call: depends(cider,_79) ? 
      2    2  Exit: depends(cider,apple) ? 
      3    2  Call: depends(apple,tree) ? 
      3    2  Exit: depends(apple,tree) ? 
      1    1  Exit: depends_on(cider,tree) ? 

yes
```

Comment: `Z` is a singleton variable in your rule, is that what you have?

Comment: I have posted my whole program here - I don't know what Prolog means by 'singleton' variable ! :-| (I'm trying to traverse from "cider depends on apple", to "apple depends on tree", by saying 'does cider depend on tree?')

Comment: A singleton variable is a variable that is not mentioned anywhere in the rule, and can therefore be ignored.

Comment: It could be anything. It means your code is identical to `depends(X,Y) :- X\==Y, depends(_,Y), depends(X,Y)`, which is obviously unbounded recursion and the source of the error.

Comment: @DanielLyons why not post it as answer? do you mean, ecause it is too trivial a typo?

Comment: I don't think it's a bad book, and you could certainly get a dose of the flavor of Prolog in a week, but you're not going to really master it in less than a few months or a year.

Comment: I'm almost tempted to write a script to generate all permuations of a prolog program and see which one works :) (What I really need is a programming language that can automate that kind of thing- oh wait....)

Comment: Actually Prolog is pretty good at generating Prolog. Check out the univ operator, `=..`.

Comment: The book is great: I was merely attempting to be amusing. (If it wasn't for the section on Prolog programs ('spells and witchcraft' more like) I wouldn't be sitting at a keyboard pulling my hair out trying to get a 4 line program working !)

Comment: On the upside - I have learnt that cider does indeed depend indirectly on the existence of trees....

Comment: @monojohnny you still have a typo. If you introduce a third layer (say, `depends(tree, worm_feces)`) you won't discover that cider depends on it until you change the second `depends` in your `depends_on` into `depends_on`. You want just the right amount of recursion. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you have a singleton variable:

```
depends(X,Y) :- X\==Y, depends(Z,Y),depends(X,Y).
```

is equivalent to:

```
depends(X,Y) :- X\==Y, depends(_,Y), depends(X,Y).
```

Prolog "warns" you about singleton variables, but you should always treat it as a serious error, because it almost always means your code isn't doing what you think it's doing. In this case, I suspect you think that Prolog will automatically make X and Z different, but it doesn't, and there's nothing else in here to instruct Prolog to do something with Z, so this is just wasted time or a copy of the real problem.

The real problem is that this code simplifies to this:

```
depends(X,Y) :- X\==Y, depends(X,Y).
```

This is unbounded recursion. I could give `depends(chickens, eggs_and_flapjacks)` and Prolog is simply going to say, "hmm, `chickens` are not the same as `eggs_and_flapjacks`, what's the next thing I have to do?" and then jump back to the beginning only to ask the question again. This results in a stack overflow exception. If you trace in, you'll see the error clearly:

```
?- trace, depends(eggs, chickens).
Call: (7) depends(eggs, chickens) ? 
Call: (8) eggs\==chickens ? 
Exit: (8) eggs\==chickens ? 
Call: (8) depends(eggs, chickens) ? 
Call: (9) eggs\==chickens ? 
Exit: (9) eggs\==chickens ? 
Call: (9) depends(eggs, chickens) ? 
Call: (10) eggs\==chickens ? 
Exit: (10) eggs\==chickens ? 
Call: (10) depends(eggs, chickens) ? 
Call: (11) eggs\==chickens ? 
Exit: (11) eggs\==chickens ? 
Call: (11) depends(eggs, chickens) ? 
Call: (12) eggs\==chickens ? 
Exit: (12) eggs\==chickens ? 
Call: (12) depends(eggs, chickens) ?
```

etc. etc.

So that's your whole problem. Your code doesn't do anything yet except loop.

**Edit** Graph traversal

You're going to need to separate your facts from your predicate for this particular problem. This isn't always the case. You're going to want this:

```
depends_on(X, Y) :- depends(X, Y).
depends_on(X, Z) :- depends(X, Y), depends_on(Y, Z).
```

This gives you bounded recursion. If you tried to do it with one predicate you'd get unbounded recursion:

```
depends(X,Z) :- depends(X,Y), depends(Y,Z).
```

There are several ways around this problem, the easiest being separating the facts from the predicate like we've done above. Some Prolog implementations support tabling, which I believe also solves this problem (am I high?); otherwise you could track which relationships you've traversed already and avoid loops that way (this is the usual way when dealing with undirected graphs).

Comment: Thanks for this - I'll need to : think_about_it(me,this).